# More than one place with same postcode causing issue

Tags: php, mysql, group-by, limit

I need to be able to group the postcodes from Aus_Postcodes in this select query, as what is happening is that the offers are looping.

Current Query:

```
SELECT approved_business.*, 
       business_stores.*, 
       group_concat(offer ORDER BY offer ASC SEPARATOR ',') as offers, 
       Aus_Postcodes.state as AusState 
FROM  approved_business, 
      business_stores, 
      Real_Cash_Offers, 
      Aus_Postcodes 
WHERE approved_business.id = business_stores.business_id AND 
      Real_Cash_Offers.business_id = approved_business.id AND 
      Real_Cash_Offers.storeid = business_stores.storeid AND 
      business_stores.postcode = Aus_Postcodes.postcode AND 
      approved_business.id = '1288' 
GROUP BY approved_business.id 
LIMIT 1
```

Here is the sample output, I have encoded it to JSON as that's what our system uses.

```
[{"id":"1288","tradingname":"Loretta Adams Bridal & Evening Wear","listed":"2012-01-26 19:26:24","pictureurl":"","business_id":"1288","storeid":"1","phone":"6139379210","street":"266 Keilor Rd","suburb":"Essendon North","state":"1","postcode":"3041","discription":"","offers":"1000|70,1000|70,1000|70,300|15,300|15,300|15,500|30,500|30,500|30","AusState":"VIC,VIC,VIC,VIC,VIC,VIC,VIC,VIC,VIC"}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `group_concat(offer ORDER BY offer ASC SEPARATOR ',') as offers` to be `group_concat(DISTINCT offer ORDER BY offer ASC SEPARATOR ',') as offers`.